# Ionic not working in IBM Mobilefirst Platform

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I created simple project in IBM Mobilefirst. I have very simple Ionic layout:

```
<body style="display: none;">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
            <button class="button button-assertive">I'm a button</button>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also, I did bootstrap of angular:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    }); 
}
angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

I included Ionic library to my project v1.2.4 and made reference for them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/ionic.css">    
<script src="lib/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

But I cannot see anything when I am previewing the App. If I am using Ionic v1.0.0 it is working. What I am doing wrong? I want to use Ionic v.1.2.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look on this blogpost, it covers the general steps to handle ionic and MFPF 7.1(in case this is your version).

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/19/developing-ionic-apps-with-mobilefirst-7-1/

If your version is 7.0, take a look on this:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/24/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-ionic-bootstraping/

Hope this info helps,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added empty "container" to the body tag which fills  whole screen. I did:

**main.css**

```
#dimScreen    
{
        position:fixed;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;

        top:0;
        left:0;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<body style="display: none;" id = "dimScreen">
            <ion-pane>
                <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
                    <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
                </ion-header-bar>
                <ion-content class="padding">
                <button class="button button-assertive">I'm a button</button>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-pane>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
```